# Groovy map method of collections

Tags: scala, groovy, functional-programming, dictionary

Is there a `map` method in Groovy? I want to do something like I do with the following Scala snippet:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.map(_ + 1)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There is such a method in groovy, it is called **`collect`**, for example:

```
assert [1, 2, 3].collect { it * 2 } == [2, 4, 6]
```

https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_iterating_on_a_list

Comment: assert [1,2,3].collect {it+1} == [2,3,4]

Comment: Quite strange function name for very popular idiom

Comment: If you think collect is strange, wait until you come across 'inject' for reduce/fold operation!

Comment: I suspect `collect` and `inject` are borrowed from methods by those names in Ruby's Enumerable mixin.

Comment: @RoyTinker, is probably correct. Groovy takes some inspiration from Ruby's function names (collect, inject), and its syntax (def, optional parens, braces for closures).

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: Thank you from the future